# How do I add quantities to the items in user input array?

Tags: php

I'm having a user input an item, and that item is being added to an array and displayed as it goes.  How might I add a quantity field and also display this quantity next to the item?  Thank you!

```
<form  method="post">
`Add a new item: <input type="text" name="new_name"/>
<input type="submit"/>

<?php
$names = postVar('names') ? : array();
$names[] = postVar('new_name');
foreach ($names as $name) {
    echo $name . "<br/>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='names[]' value='$name'/>";
}
echo "Current items on list";

function postVar($name) {
    // only if exists
    if (! isset($_POST[$name])) {
        return null;
    }
    // fetch
    $out = $_POST[$name];
    // cleanup
    if (is_array($out)) {
        return array_map('htmlspecialchars', $out);
    }
    return htmlspecialchars($out);
}
?>

</form>
```

Comment: you can use sessions so that your quantity persists

Comment: what exactly is it you are asking? And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I know you're doing this for testing and learning, so I won't go into details. In short:

1. Change line 2 from

   ```
   `Add a new item: <input type="text" name="new_name"/>
   ```

   to

   ```
   `Add a new item: <input type="text" name="new_name"/>, <input type="text" name="qty"/> pcs
   ```
2. Change lines 7-9 from

   ```
   $names[] = postVar('new_name');
   foreach ($names as $name) {
   echo $name . "<br/>";
   ```

   to

   ```
   $names[postVar('new_name')] = postVar('qty');
   foreach ($names as $name => $qty) {
   echo $name . ", qty: " . $qty . "<br/>";
   ```

I let you figure out yourself - this is the best way to learn. Read about [arrays in PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).